# How can I increase GPU Quota for User-Managed Notebooks | Google Cloud Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have been able to increase my quota for 'Managed Notebooks NVIDIA T4 GPUs per region'
to two, but because of a current issue in Managed Notebooks, I need to create a User-Managed Notebook. I'm unable to create a 'User-Managed Notebook' or an 'Instance' with GPUs, and It gives me a vague error about how there's no resources in my region at this time, even though I can create a Managed Notebook with GPUs no problem in the same region. So, I believe the issue is with some quota, but I don't know which one.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Alekk, it appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/?hl=en). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: Always include the exact error message. What might be vague for you might not be for others.

Answer (score 0):

User Managed Notebook use GCE Quota, just like regular VMs

Comment: No matter what I do, I still get the following vague, useless error message: 
"The zone 'projects/kaggle-413523/zones/<ANY_REGION>' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.: Something went wrong. Sorry about that."

Comment: That is not a Quota, that is stockout. Meaning there is not available resources at a time for you. Have you tried reservations or G2 family? https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Community-Blogs/Managing-Capacity-Quota-and-Stockouts-in-the-Cloud-Concepts-and/ba-p/464770#toc-hId-1635110264

Comment: I will look into it. 
Why is it so hard to give y'all money lol?